# Remove columns when exporting data when using datatable.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working on a project and i wanted to remove specific columns when exporting a table to pdf.  So i used the code from datatables.net and here is my code for exporting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var currentDate = new Date()
        var day = currentDate.getDate()
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear()


        var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
        $('#detailTable').DataTable( {
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [ 
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: d+ ' Purchase Orders'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    title: d+ ' Purchase Orders'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    title: d+ ' Purchase Orders',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                }
             ]
        } );
    });
```

I made it landscape since the table is kinda long and here is the output of the pdf i exported (I censored some values sorry for that)
[image]

Is there a way that i can remove that column where the values are 'edit'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: checkout this jsfiddle if its helps you http://jsfiddle.net/andrew_safwat/cn1n060L/

Comment: thanks! just added it! :)

Comment: @prashant Thanks for the live jsfiddle. It helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set column index to hide column for exporting from datatable, You have to add column option in button attribute like following example :-

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
    "sScrollY": "350px",
    "bPaginate": false,
    "sDom": 'lfrtip<"clear spacer">T',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/flash/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "mColumns": [0, 1, 3, 4]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "mColumns": [0, 1, 3, 4]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "mColumns": [0, 1, 3, 4]
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "print",
                "mColumns": [0, 1, 3, 4]
            },
        ]
    }
});
```

You can visit these url for more help
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/3210/tabletools-how-to-hide-columns-when-exporting-copying

It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to utilize HTML to control the feel of my table which reduces the Javascript I need to write for *common* implementations of the Datatables so instead of utilizing specific column numbers (`columns: [0, 1, 2]`) I utilize a jQuery selector.

Specifically in my software I have columns for button actions, that generally look miserable in the

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    dom: 'Bfrtlip',
    lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 250, -1], [10, 25, 50, 250, "All"]],
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: "thead th:not(.noExport)"
            }
        }
        //'copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'print' // , 'pdf' - Wait for next PDFMake release because of this bug https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/pull/443
    ]
});
```

now my table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
            <th class="noExcel">Column to Hide</th>
            <th>Fourth Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First Column value</td>
            <td>Second Column value</td>
            <td>Column to Hide value</td>
            <td>Fourth Column value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the $("table").Datatables()  is called it will have buttons for Copy > Excel > CSV > Print    but each of them will ignore the 3rd column which has the class "noExport".